# Nginx MySQL Query and get results

Tags: mysql, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I was wondering if it was possible to capture the http_header and than query that into MySQL and get the backend IP and set that was the proxy_pass. I have multiple websites and I need a efficient way to do this.

All the backends are in the SQL database along with the server_name, so I would want to just make one configuration file and depending on the URL request the proxy_pass backend IP would be different.

Thank you